# Foundation 5 - combine top navigation with off canvas?

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I am new to Foundation, I have looked at using it multiple times but have always disregarded it as it doesn't seem to have many navigation options available.  All of the options available  apply to a top menu.  What about left or right? I usually need to build websites with complex navigation and usually require a top menu and a left hand menu including searches, drop downs and other sub menus.

I could probably use foundation if it is possible to have both the top menu and the off canvas navigation from a left hand column. Does anyone know if this is possible and where I would go to for assistance with setting this up?

Comment: Are you sure you really look at it? how about [this website](http://zurb.com/responsive/site/186-tapeandmedia?framework_id=&name_or_style=&style_id=) you can find much more examples on [their Library](http://zurb.com/responsive) (currently 181 examples)... from those 181 there's nothing that resembles what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: yes I think so.  That example only has top navigation, not any side navigation thats responsive

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep both menus accessible to you at all times, but only make them show using `show-for-small` and `show-for-medium-up` classes.

You'll need to use separate sets of navigation in order to achieve what you're wanting. In order to use both, however, you'll need to structure your website to accommodate the off-canvas menu and build the top-nav within the `main-section`.

We recently came across this issue with our corporate site and we only wanted to call the navigation once, however it was proving extremely difficult. If you want to see a live version of the code feel free to use [our site](http://www.corporate3design.com/home) as a reference. (We have classes to hide the off-canvas menu for `medium-and-up`, but you can just remove it).

Here's a basic example of how the structure would look:

```
  <div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>
    <div class="inner-wrap">                

      <nav class="tab-bar">
        <section class="left-small">
          <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" ><span></span></a>
         </section>

        <section class="middle tab-bar-section">
          <h1 class="title"><a href="/home"><img id="logoSmall" src="/images/main/header_logo_small.png" /></a></h1>
        </section>
      </nav>

      <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
        <ul class="off-canvas-list">
          <li><label>Menu</label></li>
          <li><a>link1</a></li>
          <li><a>link2</a></li>
          <li><a>link2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </aside>



      <section class="main-section">

        <!-- All of your website goes here -->
        <!-- Including the top navigation and all that jazz -->

      </section>

      <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>
    </div><!--/innerWrapp-->
  </div><!--/offCanvasWrap-->
```